# Появление фотографий после их загрузки

Tags: javascript, jquery

Еесть фотки на сайте, которые динамически подгружаются и скорость загрузки зависит от интернета, фото стоят изначально в `jQuery('img').css({'opacity': '0'});`

Нужно, чтобы они стали `jQuery('img').css({'opacity': '1'});` только после того, как полностью загрузились на стороне клиента.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
 img{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  transition: all .5s
 }
</style>
<body>
 <img src="img/1.jpg">
 <img src="img/2.jpg">
 <img src="img/3.jpg">
 <img src="img/4.jpg">
 <img src="img/5.jpg">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery('img').css({'opacity': '0'});


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Есть такая штука lazyload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я делаю это так:

```js
$('img[data-src]').each(function() { // перебираем все img с атрибутом data-src
  var img = $(this);
  img.attr('src', img.attr('data-src')); // подставляем адрес в src
  img.on('load', function() { // после загрузки изображения
    img.removeAttr('data-src'); // убираем атрибут data-src, после чего отображается загруженное изображение 
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 200px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

img[data-src] {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img data-src="http://files.all-free-download.com//downloadfiles/wallpapers/1920_1080/heihachi_mishima_tekken_7_4k_17496.jpg" alt="" />
<img data-src="http://files.all-free-download.com//downloadfiles/wallpapers/1920_1080/forza_horizon_3_hd_xbox_one_17493.jpg" alt="" />
<img data-src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_thum/teenage_mutant_ninja_turtle_out_of_the_shadows_5k_17489.jpg" alt="" />
<img data-src="http://files.all-free-download.com//downloadfiles/wallpapers/1920_1080/justice_league_2017_movie_17488.jpg" alt="" />
<img data-src="http://files.all-free-download.com//downloadfiles/wallpapers/1920_1080/dont_breathe_2016_horror_movie_17475.jpg" alt="" />
```

---

Этот же вариант на чисто JS:

```js
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('img[data-src]'), function(img) { // перебираем все img с атрибутом data-src
  img.setAttribute('src', img.getAttribute('data-src')); // подставляем адрес в src
  img.onload = function() { // после загрузки изображения
    img.removeAttribute('data-src'); // убираем атрибут data-src, после чего отображается загруженное изображение 
  };
});
```

```css
img {
  max-width: 200px;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

img[data-src] {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<img data-src="http://files.all-free-download.com//downloadfiles/wallpapers/1920_1080/heihachi_mishima_tekken_7_4k_17496.jpg" alt="" />
<img data-src="http://files.all-free-download.com//downloadfiles/wallpapers/1920_1080/forza_horizon_3_hd_xbox_one_17493.jpg" alt="" />
<img data-src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/wallpapers_thum/teenage_mutant_ninja_turtle_out_of_the_shadows_5k_17489.jpg" alt="" />
<img data-src="http://files.all-free-download.com//downloadfiles/wallpapers/1920_1080/justice_league_2017_movie_17488.jpg" alt="" />
<img data-src="http://files.all-free-download.com//downloadfiles/wallpapers/1920_1080/dont_breathe_2016_horror_movie_17475.jpg" alt="" />
```